# Do I need to add all packages from nuget into TFS source control if I want a CI setup?

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, tfs, continuous-integration, nuget

I'm using team foundation service with Git, and I notice when I first checked in my code, all the dlls in the packages folder were not included.

1) If I want to set up CI on the cloud, would I then have to include all these nuget packages into source control?

2) If I have multiple projects, do I have to upload the same dlls for each project into source control also?

3) What is a common strategy to multiple projects, all of them with very similar, if not similar dll references when checking them into source control + CI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [NuGet Package Restore](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages).
In a nutshell, it will automatically download missing packages from nuget.org, so you don't have do commit them.

The latest version (2.7) introduced some breaking changes so check the version you are using...

Comment: One issue to be aware of, if you don't have the packages folder in your repository, is that some packages are removed from Nuget. So, at a later date, other people may not be able to download/restore them. I had an issue with Office API that was removed by Microsoft and we had serious issues restoring and upgrading to a newer version.

Comment: @Miro you are right, it's really uncommon but of course it can happen. If you are working on an enterprise project my advice is ALWAYS use a private NuGet server.